# uniqueidentifier as argument in url | django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, python-3.x, django-views

I am trying to create **CRUD** project in Django. I successfully connected with database in MS SQL SERVER, also successfully made migration with my model. Now when I tried I to show list of data in webpage I have next **ERROR**:

> NoReverseMatch
>
> Reverse for 'extraction_edit' with arguments
>   '('A4A49247-B940-450C-8E1E-2F8148CB0933',)' and keyword arguments '{}'
>   not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['crud/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']`

and shows that something wrong in my template:

```
<a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_edit' extraction.id_extraction %}">edit</a>
<a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_delete' extraction.id_extraction %}">delete</a>
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem?!

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ExtractionUpdate.as_view(), name='extraction_edit'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.ExtractionDelete.as_view(), name='extraction_delete'),
)
```

**extraction_list.html**

```
    <h1>Extractions list</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for extraction in object_list %}
            <li>ExtractionID-{{ extraction.id_extraction }}   Date-{{ extraction.name_extraction }}
                <a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_edit' extraction.id_extraction %}">edit</a>
                <a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_delete' extraction.id_extraction %}">delete</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_new' %}">New</a>
```

**models.py**

```
class Extraction(models.Model):
    id_extraction = models.CharField(db_column='ID_Extraction', max_length=36,  primary_key=True)
    name_extraction = models.CharField(db_column='Name_Extraction', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Extraction'
```

`EDIT`:

**model.py**

```
def get_edit_url(self):
    return reverse('extraction_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.id_extraction})
```

**urls.py**

```
<a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_edit' extraction.get_edit_url %}">EDIT</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your urlpattern extraction_edit you have one keyword argument pk. But you did not specify it in your template. 
Instead of

```
<a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_edit' extraction.id_extraction %}">edit</a>
```

rewrite href attribute like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'crud:extraction_edit' pk=extraction.id_extraction %}">edit</a>
```

Quote from Django [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/topics/http/urls/):

The keyword arguments are made up of any named groups matched by the regular expression, overridden by any arguments specified in the optional kwargs argument to django.conf.urls.url().

Comment: Well, I rewrite as you said but unfortunatly I have the same mistake just with little differens django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'extraction_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 'A4A49247-B940-450C-8E1E-2F8148CB0933'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['crud/edit/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

Comment: By the way can I had the same error when used the code in edit part of my post. Can you check post again? I think problem is here `edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$` my pk is uniqueidentifier here as you see.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek try to change regular expression in your pattern: instead of '\d+' use '[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+'.